# Why am i getting these error while executing the snmpset command?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmp4j, snmpd, snmp-trap

**snmpset  -OQ -v 2c -c   SNMPv2-MIB::ocStbHostRebootReset.0 i = 1**

above written is the code I have executed this in putty as I have to reboot the box, so for true value, i am giving as i=1.

*but I am getting below error after executing this*

**snmpset: Unknown host (SNMPv2-MIB::ocStbHostRebootReset.0) (No such file or directory)**

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that **-c** option is used to specify the community string not the variable to set. Also you have not specified the IP address of your device/host. Your command should look like:

```
snmpset -v 2c -c public 192.168.100.10 SNMPv2-MIB::ocStbHostRebootReset.0 i 1
```

The other thing is the `ocStbHostRebootReset.0` is a part of `OC-STB-HOST-MIB` MIB module not the `SNMPv2-MIB`